# Segmentation fault: 11 when calling stemming function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

My program stops when finishing the first line of txt files. The program works fine without addition of filter function. Can anyone point out the error?

Output:

```
the
project
gutenberg
ebook
of
alic
s
adventur
in
wonderland
by
lewi
carroll
```

Segmentation fault: 11

The code for the program is the following:

```c
int main(void) {

    char line[MAXLINE];
    FILE *text = fopen("test_1.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), text)!= NULL) {
        //reading to the end
        if (strstr(line, ENDING) != NULL) break;
        //tokenise the string
        char *lower_line = strlwr(line);
        char * pch = filter(strtok(line, " ,.-?"));
        while (pch != NULL){
            printf("%s\n", pch);
            pch = filter(strtok(NULL, " ,.-?'"));
        }
    }
    fclose(text);
}

char *filter (char *word){

    int k = stem(word, 0, strlen(word)-1);
    word[k+1] = '\0';
    return word;

}


char* strlwr(char* s){

    char* tmp = s;
    for (;*tmp;++tmp) {
        *tmp = tolower((unsigned char) *tmp);
    }
    return s;

}
```

Comment: What is `stem` which is both a variable and a function? Function `filter()` is writing to the string you are splitting in `main`, using an index supplied by the unknown function `stem()`.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem, and the line that is given for input, and a description of what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: I'm trying to update pch by my filter function. Passing in a string of word and obtain a new word from stem function.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot guess what the `stem()` function does.

Comment: It tries to trim the size of word down. e.g. apples into "apple", loves and lovesss into "lov"

Answer (score 1):

in the last cycle of this loop

```
while (pch != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", pch);
    pch = filter(strtok(NULL, " ,.-?'"));
}
```

you are passing NULL reference into the *"filter"* function,
this makes sure that when you get NULL reference it doesn't run

```
   while (pch != NULL){
        pch = filter(pch);
        printf("%s\n", pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ,.-?'");
    }
```